# How to remove consecutive occurrences of a pattern in a string C# / Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a problem to normalize words and sentences.

For e.g. Yahoooo -> Yaho

Yeeeesssss -> yes,

hahahahahaha -> ha

hello world hello world hello world -> hello world

Basically any pattern that occurs more than 2 times needs to be normalized to one occurrence.

**Edit1:** Based on the questions below, I'm adding more cases

"hello world hello hello heheheheheheheheheh" - "hello world hello hello he".

"hello world hello world hello world" - "hello world".

"aaabbb aaabbb aaabbb" - "ab ab ab" - "ab" (final output).

So > 2 occurrences is the condition and all the filters (unigram, bigram, trigram till let's say 5grams) should be applied.

Comment: what about `"hello world hello hello heheheheheheheheheh"`

Comment: Why wouldn't `"hello world hello world hello world"` go to `"helo world"` (as the `'l'` is duplicated too)?

Comment: What about `aaabbb aaabbb aaabbb`? How do you decide when a pattern occurence ends? What happens when repeated items are not consecutive? I'm no regex expert but I think this is not possible in regex (and even if it is, it's probably far easier to implement it in logic rather than regex).

Comment: "hello world hello hello heheheheheheheheheh"  - "hello world hello hello he". 


"hello world hello world hello world" - "hello world". 


"aaabbb aaabbb aaabbb" - "ab ab ab" - "ab" (final output). 


So > 2 occurrences is the condition and all the filters (unigram, bigram, trigram till let's say 5grams) should be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
string input = @"hello world hello hello hehehehehehehehehe aaabbb aaabbb aaabbb";

while(input.Length != (input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(.+)\1{2,}", "$1")).Length);

Console.WriteLine(input);
```

With the Regex `(.+)\1{2,}` which means match one or more characters that are repeated two or more times. It produce the following output:

> hello world hello hello he ab

[<kbd>Run it live</kbd>](http://ideone.com/UIUFgF)